# IIS 7 and Windows 2008: only one ip address showing for IIS binding when multiple aliases exist?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, bindings, ip-aliasing

In Windows 2003 I have multiple IP aliases setup on a single network card all bound to IIS 6.

In Windows 2008 I have multiple IP aliases setup but only one shows up in IIS 7.

What do I need to do to have the other IPs show up?  It gives choices of all unassigned or the main IP address.  I have obviously tried restarting the machine.

I tried both using host headers and no headers.  I also double checked the firewall and DNS settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything interesting installed on the machine? Fresh install? What else is configured on it so far? does 'Netsh http sh ipl' show you anything interesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with IIS UI. You can manually add the required IP in the IP Address section.